# How to configure jetty in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, html, websocket, jetty

I found this [tutorial](http://jansipke.nl/websocket-tutorial-with-java-server-jetty-and-javascript-client/) that makes my case.

But the problem is that I can not configure Eclipse to use jetty.
I imported the libraries in eclipse, but it always fails in some import.

Who can help me with simple steps to follow?
I need to integrate some servers? (For example tomcat)

Excuse me, but it is my first encounter with websocket and java, and not know where to start
thank you very much

[This is a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGz2W.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

> [Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading to a stable and supported version of Jetty.

`org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api` is not present in Jetty 7.

That was introduced in Jetty 9.

Use Jetty 9.4.3.v20170317